# OpenCV 3.2.0-dev - 3.2.0 version missing RTrees, unable to find dev version

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, fedora, opencv3.2

***OpenCV 3.2.0*** seems does not have ***RTrees library***.

But internet is full of examples of ***cv2.RTrees***. I thought maybe be the issue of versions mismatching - maybe version is wrong ? Should it be ***3.2.0-dev*** ?

But on ***Fedora 24*** i cant seem to find this package nor on the internet. All i see that only ubuntu users can install 3.2.0-dev. Am i missing something ?

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.2.0'
>>> cv2.RTrees
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RTrees'
>>> cv2.ml.RTrees
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RTrees'
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16 with` OpenCV` version 3.2.0 and also get those errors

Comment: Apparently, this issue was fixed, recently. I'll post it in my answer. Updating to latest version should solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most examples of `RTrees` you could find before this date on the internet are from versions `2.4.x`. This is because as of mid January  there was still no wrapper for Python of the `RTrees` model of OpenCV, as we can see in [this question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/122375/how-to-load-a-trained-random-trees-model-in-opencv-3-in-python/) on the OpenCV answers page. Quoting from it (user *berak* on Jan 12 '17:

> unfortunately, this is not possible atm., as of opencv3.2, only SVM and ANN_MLP have correctly wrapped load methods.
>
> (yes, it's a bug)

Searching a bit more it was found that this issue was fixed recently (as pointed out in [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/128921/random-trees-in-opencv-with-python-load-method-missing/) question); you can see this functionality was added in this [pull request](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/8004) on the OpenCV git.

Therefore, **updating** to the latest master branch and **rebuilding** should fix the problem.

**Note:** Remember to clone the main repository ([opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)), which is the one who actually contains the `RTrees` model, and if you are using it also clone the contrib repository ([opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)). Do checkout the same version on each to avoid compatibility issues.

**Bonus:** Check [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/) great installation guide for OpenCV, which also provides some additional recommendations like using `venv` for the installation (it also has guides for other OS).

Comment: Cloned 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git

Then did chekout on 3.2.0 version

Installed using cmake and make (whatever is written in tutorials)

Still cant find the method.

Comment: Did you also updated and rebuilt the main repo (not only the "contrib" one)? Remember that the contrib one only has the extra modules (usually not fully supported and experimental). You should be cloning this one also: https://github.com/opencv/opencv . I will update my answer to clarify that, and also share a great link for OpenCV installation I found.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Marked as an answer.